# Get changed files from SVN command line between two revisions

Tags: svn, diff, revision

I need to get the changed files list between two revisions in SVN.

I have used the following command:

```
svn diff -r 5001:6001 --summarize https://svn.blah.com/../  > output.txt
```

For some reason, the files modified on revision 5001 are not populated in the output text file.

What is the exact command to extract the files list between the two revisions (inclusive of from and to revisions, that is, including revision 5001 and revision 6001)?

Comment: yeah i have tried -r 5000:6001 it does includes the files modified on r 5001 but not 5000....                                                  Does this mean i have to always decrement by one revision number

Comment: Yes. That's the way it works.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try `svn diff -r 5000:6001` instead. To understand this, consider the following: what would the output of `svn diff -r 100:100` look like? It would show no changes, because the revisions are the same. To see the changes for revision 100, we must use `-r 99:100`.

Comment: Right - as there is no difference between 100 and 100 - they are identical. By definition. Hence if you want to know the difference in your 5001:6001 inclusive of 5001 one needs to do a -r 5000:6001.

Answer (score 11):

Try `svn log -r 5000:6001 -v` to get the list of files. This gives list of files categorized by revision no. So, one can have better idea on what files went in what revision at a glance.

Comment: I needed a list of the files that had changed between two arbitrary revisions and this worked for me, while the diff -r suggestion, with --summarize or not listed all the files in the repo. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Be careful about the output of this when there are revisions coming from merges. Experience an issue today where the output looked like /branch/abc/new_file.js (from trunk/new_file.js:12344). In my experience you are always better of using --xml if you are planning consuming this data as the input of something else.

Answer (score 8):

Dirk-Willem van Gulik's answer is perfect if you want all changes. However if you want only the list of files changed append --summarize switch to your command,

```
svn diff -r 13447:HEAD
```

Answer (score 8):

`svn diff -r v1:v2 --summarize | awk '{print $2}' > filelist.txt`

Explanation:

`svn diff -r v1:v2 --summarize` provides you the status and the name of the file separated by a tab character. You need to select the string after the tab character - the second field. You can do that using `awk` and redirect the output to `filelist.txt`

Answer (score -1):

```
svn diff -r 5001:6001 ...local path hier ...  > output.txt
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation as to why this solves the user's problem?